Changing SDDM login screen on Ubuntu Studio 24.04 ? System doesn't allow any change
I am using Ubuntu Studio 24.04. Current SDDM (display manager) is "Ubuntu Studio", which does not allow me to select a user who is not in the list....
I have been trying to select another display manager, e.g. "Breeze", but my system doesn't allow any change and goes back to "Ubuntu Studio"...
Any idea ?!
Thanks !
Vincent
